# Which one is better a balanced binary search tree or the max-heap for extracting the max element?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-heap

Since a Balanced `BST` would take `O(log(n))` time is extracting the max **(by extracting I mean both find and delete Max element)**.
On the other hand `Max-heap` would also take `O(log(n))` time in extracting the max element.

Does anyone of them has cutting edge over the other in Extract-Max operation?

Comment: I know that. But what if we want to perform extract-max kinda operation. So which one will be the suitable data structure a balanced bst or max heap.

Comment: In some special cases `BST` would take only one operation more than `Heap` otherwise both can extract max in same number of operation. But that one more operation is negligible .

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS Finding the Right most node of the Balanced Bst would take O(log(n)) and performing a delete operation would take O(1).

Comment: Okay finding max element will take O( log n ) time, as we need to find the rightmost element and then deletion would take O(1) as it would be a leaf node or a node with only one child. Correct@ Sanket Makani and @Satyendra

Answer (score 0):

When thinking of data structures, you should take into account their complexities, both of time and space. Here space is the same, so let's focus on time:

**Balanced BST:**

> balanced BST maintains h = O(lg n) ⇒ all operations run in O(lg n) time.

**Max-Heap**:

> Find max O(1), Delete max O(lg n)

which means that their time complexities are also the same.

Also by reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1913236/2411320), you draw the same conclusion:

> ...a max-heap or a binary tree is a good fit.

However, note that balancing an already constructed BST is an O(n) operation ([Balancing a BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001676/balancing-a-bst)). So if I had to do that too, then I would go for a max heap.

For advanced usage, read [Which data structure to use for accessing min/max in constant-time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19518/which-data-structure-to-use-for-accessing-min-max-in-constant-time)

---

<sub>Sources: [1](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall09/lecture_notes/lecture04.pdf), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).</sub>

Comment: So whats your conclusion on this?

Comment: So for that operation both are fine when it comes to efficiency. If I were you, I would see which is easier to be implemented, or whether I have access to a library that provides such a data structure. For example, if I am writing in [tag:c++] and there is a library that I like, which provides a heap, I would go for that!

Comment: I think balancing the tree is an overhead. And I am not concerned about simplicity of implementation for now.

Comment: Oh I thought the question was, that given I have these data structures already, what's better @SatyendraYadav. Yes it is, let me update my answer. By the way, you can ask a new question, instead of editing the one you have already posted and got an answer for it. That way we maintain the compactness of the posts! =)

Comment: @gsamaras You have provided a link about balancing a BST , but there the user balances a whole tree, which is initially unbalanced. But in this case rebalancing is required only after delete operation(and that too only in some cases) and will not take O(n) time. Balancing a previously unbalanced tree is different from balancing that is performed in this case.

Comment: Correct @GAURANGVYAS! That's another question Mr. Yadav.